# JavaScript autocomplete cascading drop-down/input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a code for dependent drop-down with autocomplete. I can see the values in drop-down by first letters typed in input. How to make it show if any letter typed into the input match any letters of the values in the array and highlight the letters that match. See example [here on Github](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#basic-usage).

```
 var states = {
  'Color': ['red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', ],
  'Numbers': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
};

function initDialog() {
  clearDialog();
  var $locations = jQuery('#location');

  jQuery(document).on("change", "#country", function() {
        var country = $(this).val(),
          lcns = states[country] || [];

        var html = jQuery.map(lcns, function(lcn) {
          return '<div>' + lcn + '</div>'
        }).join('');
        $locations.html(html)
        if (jQuery('#country').val() == "color") {

          function match(str) {

            str = str.toLowerCase();
            clearDialog();
            for (var i = 0; i < states.color.length; i++) {
              if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(str)) {
                jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');
              }
            }
          }
          var states = {
            'Color': ['red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', ],
            'Numbers': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
          };

          function initDialog() {
            clearDialog();
            var $locations = jQuery('#location');

            jQuery(document).on("change", "#country", function() {
                  var country = $(this).val(),
                    lcns = states[country] || [];

                  var html = jQuery.map(lcns, function(lcn) {
                    return '<div>' + lcn + '</div>'
                  }).join('');
                  $locations.html(html)
                  if (jQuery('#country').val() == "color") {

                    function match(str) {

                      str = str.toLowerCase();
                      clearDialog();
                      for (var i = 0; i < states.color.length; i++) {
                        if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(str)) {
                          jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');
                        }
                      }
                    }
```

Comment: The url you posted doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like there's a function `match` for some reasons defined within `if()` block in the last part of your code. Why's that so? This function is just defined, not executed anyway in the given code.

Comment: its just for dependent dropdown , letters matching code starts from for()

Comment: Your code seems very incomplete

Comment: use this in your if condition in for loop states.color[i].toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())

Comment: its not working